# Read HTTP error code when trying to load a JS file

Tags: javascript, html, http, error-handling

I created a function to load a JS file on demand

```
export const loadJS = url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = () => {
      resolve();
    };
    script.onerror = () => {
      reject();
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
};
```

I want to read the HTTP error code when I try to load the JS. The event object passed to the onError handler does not have the error code in it.

I tried to read the error object like below

```
event.target.error
```

but this returns **undefined**.

Comment: Can't find references to this on MDN, but this article states: _Please note that we can’t get HTTP error details here. We don’t know if it was an error 404 or 500 or something else. Just that the loading failed._ - https://javascript.info/onload-onerror